# Android studio Gradle "exclude" is not working as intended

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-firestore

Gradle exclude doesn't work as expected.
Currently, I'm using Firebase Firestore in android application, Firestore uses "protobuf-lite" internally which conflict with another library that uses "protobuf-java" which produces duplicate class gradle error and build fail.

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Any found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Any$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AnyProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Api found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0)
```

I added a rule to Firestore implementation to exclude these modules that conflict with other libraries

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module:'protolite-well-known-types'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module:'protobuf-lite'
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module:'protobuf-lite'
})
```

Now, the project built successfully and the app runs but the app crashes when I make any Firestore operation which means that they are excluded from Firestore library itself not only from the app module.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (20.1.0).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$5(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:379)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$5.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse: void com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.mergeCommitTime(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp) failed to verify: void com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.mergeCommitTime(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp): [0x10] register v3 has type Precise Reference: com.google.protobuf.Timestamp but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLiteVerifier rejected class com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse: java.lang.Object com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.dynamicMethod(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) failed to verify: java.lang.Object com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.dynamicMethod(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object): [0x73] register v5 has type Precise Reference: com.google.protobuf.Timestamp but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite (declaration of 'com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse' appears in /data/app/com.demo.myapplication-2/base.apk)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.getDefaultInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:1012)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.FirestoreGrpc.getWriteMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:379)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WriteStream.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:74)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.createWriteStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:104)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:186)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:263)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:117)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$Lambda$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$4(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:311)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$4.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:287)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$3.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

The question is: 
Doesn't exclude means that don't import these modules from Firestore library to the app module but don't remove them from Firestore?
If not, then how can I make them only available for internal Firestore usage only and hidden from the app module to avoid any conflict and duplicate class errors.

======= Update ==========
I fixed the problem
As we can't change the Firestore internal code that depends on protolite version then the only way was changing the other module that depends on proto-java to use protolite to fix this duplicate error, and to do that
I had to use protobuf lite compiler to generate java classes from the proto files which will generate classes that depend on the protolite library instead of proto-jave and now I can use the proto-lite library for both Firestore and the other Module and duplicate classes error gone.

Comment: I get the feeling you're not that clear on how classpaths work. You have a single collection of jars which make up your classpath (and yes, you can have a different classpath for compile, test and run). But for each operation (compile, test, run) there's a single, shared, classpath

Comment: Yes, it seems that "exclude" removes the module from the entire classpath, Could you suggest a way to fix this class duplicate error?

Comment: I really don't know anything about your dependencies. Perhaps protobuf-java and protobuf-lite do the same thing so you should only have one on the classpath? Have you tried excluding one at a time? As a hack maybe you could unzip one of the jars, remove the duplicate classes and zip it up again and depend on the hacked jar instead?